# What is the meaning of "getScrollX and getScrollY" in View

Tags: android, scrollview, android-view

Recently I want to write a custom view which is related to scroll. **When I use `scrollTo(100,0)`, accounting the view will move right, but the result is that the view move left.**

I know `scrollTo` means that the view content moves not the view moves, but the official docs not say it clearly. I am really confused about it.

Comment: it simply means that after `scrollTo(100,0)` the content's pixel (100, 0) will be shown at top-left corner of your view

Comment: thank you ,your explaination makes sense.

Comment: do you know how does it work  in Android source code ?

Comment: http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#12414

Answer (score 2):

**android:scrollX**

The initial horizontal scroll offset, in pixels.

Must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).

**android:scrollY**

The initial vertical scroll offset, in pixels.

Must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).

[Read this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollX)